# Not able to update Django model with HTMX button click

Tags: python, django, tailwind-css, htmx

I am using Django, Tailwind CSS, and HTMX.

I am trying to update my Django model (`Item`) which starts as `None` to use a dropdown `select` to change the color then use a button to Save and update the `Item.color` on the Django model. The HTML shows up, and I am able to make the request (the url shows up: "https://localhost/detail-view/my-item-2/?id=my-item-2&color=YELLOW"), but the model is not being updated and I can't get the `JsonResponse`s to show up. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with how I am using my POST request? Can anyone help?

models.py

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    color = models.CharField(
        "Color",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        choices=MyConstants.Color.choices,
    )
```

constants.py

```py
class Color(models.TextChoices):
    RED = "RED"
    YELLOW = "YELLOW"
    GREEN = "GREEN"
```

views.py

```py
@require_POST
def update_color(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_status = request.POST.get("color")
        item_id = request.POST.get("item_id")        
        
        item = Items.objects.filter(id=item_id)
        item.update_or_create(
            color=new_color
        )
        item.save()
        
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Color updated successfully"})
    
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Not a post request: failed to update color"})
```

color_picker.html

```html
{% block main_content %}
  <div class="p-5">
    <div class="mb-6">
      <h1 class="text-2xl">Overview</h1>
      <p class="text-sm">{{ item.id }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-4">
      <label for="color" class="text-lg ">Color</label>
      <form 
        hx-post="{% url "update_color" %}"
        hx-swap="outerHTML"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ item.id }}"/>
        <div class="flex">
          <select 
            id="color"
            name="color"
            class="w-1/4 p-2"
          >
            <option 
              value=""
              {% if not color %}selected{% endif %}
              >Choose a score</option>
            <option 
              key="GREEN"
              value="GREEN"
              {% if color and color.value == "GREEN" %}selected{% endif %}
            >RED </option>
            <option
              key="YELLOW"
              value="YELLOW"
              {% if color and color.value == "YELLOW" %}selected{% endif %}
            >YELLOW </option>
            <option
              key="RED"
              value="RED"
              {% if color and color.value == "RED" %}selected{% endif %}
            >GREEN </option>
          </select>
          <button 
            type="submit"
            class="text-white bg-blue-300"
          >Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path(r"update_color/", update_color, name="update_color"),
]
```

Comment: You use `item_id` as field but you provide `id` as a url param key. Could that be the issue?
Also when using htmx you should return html , not json.
Lastly - make sure you use csrf token in your form, it seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

no `{% csrf token %}` = no unsafe requests.
Though if you need to check if it came from htmx you still need:

`if request.META.get("HTTP_HX_REQUEST"):`

in which case you may consider django-htmx if you haven't found it yet, simple to implement. pip install django-htmx, add django_htmx to apps, add middleware

basic example but it has many things

"your_app/views.py"

```
def update_color(request):
    if request.htmx
```

Which you can set-and-forget in your base.html and not think about it too much.

```
{% load static %}
{% load django_htmx %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
  ...
  <body hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
  <script src="{% static 'js/htmx.min.js' %}" defer></script>{# or however you include htmx #}
  {% django_htmx_script %}
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. this is not DRY

```
@require_POST
def update_color(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
```

Django documentation:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def my_view(request):
    # I can assume now that only GET or POST requests make it this far
    # ...
    pass
```